# How do I call prediction function in pyspark?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am converting my sklearn code to pyspark, I was able to do it with the help of the link.

https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-pyspark-7d78d022ed35

Now I have difficulty calling a prediction method. In the sklearn used, code below to return the value of the multi cast algorithm

```
predictions = p.predict_proba (['My text 1', 'My text 2'))

totalItens = predictions.shape[0]

for i in range(0, totalItens):
    print('PROD:->')
    print(sorted(zip(p.classes_, predictions[i]), key=lambda x:x[1] , reverse=True))
```

How should I do pyspark?

Code PySpark

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="filtered", outputCol="rawFeatures", numFeatures=10000)
idf = IDF(inputCol="rawFeatures", outputCol="features", minDocFreq=5) #minDocFreq: remove sparse terms
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[regexTokenizer, stopwordsRemover, hashingTF, idf, label_stringIdx])
pipelineFit = pipeline.fit(data)
dataset = pipelineFit.transform(data)
```

Here remove 80/20

```
#(trainingData, testData) = dataset.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2], seed = 100)

trainingData = dataset
#testData = datasetTrain

lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=20, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0)
lrModel = lr.fit(trainingData)

#predictions = lrModel.transform(testData)
```

Comment: If the answer resolved your issue, kindly accept it, otherwise please leave feedback - thanks

Answer (score 7):

In Spark ML (not to be confused with the older MLlib), the method for getting predictions in unseen data is `transform`, which holds both for stand-alone ML models as well as for [pipelines](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#how-it-works):

[image]

So, you first fit your pipeline to the training data with

```
pipeline.fit(data) # no need for pipelineFit
```

and then you get predictions on new data with:

```
pred = pipeline.transform(newData)
```

The same holds true for your logistic regression; in fact you don't need `lrModel` - you simply need:

```
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=20, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0) # define model
lr.fit(trainingData) # fit to training data
predictions = lr.transform(testData) # get predictions of test data
```

Comment: What if you just want to predict on a new example not belonging to the testing data? Do you just do `pipeline.transform(newTuple)` ?

Comment: @Álvaro yes; although using Spark for single sample predictions sounds like overkill.

Comment: I will add that I had to convert my data for prediction to dataFrame format, and that I had to specify a label nonetheless: `df = spark.createDataFrame([(1.0, Vectors.dense([10, 12, -1, 4]))], ["label", "features"])`
`prediction = model.transform(df)`

Comment: @Álvaro Comments are not the appropriate space for such extended discussions (plus it's not clear what your exact issue is); please open a new question with any issues you may encounter.